# How to get retrieve an image from a mysql database and echo it out in php?

Tags: php, mysql

How can I get an Image from a mysql database and echo it to the screen??

I have this script to get the information from the database:

```
/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
echo("Connection Error: ". mysqli_connect_error());
} else {
$query = "SELECT * FROM games";
if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $query)) {

    /* fetch associative array */
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
}
}
```

but when I try to echo the image to the screen I get this:

```
ï öË>Ti¥òÅ¦„u`¨c’–÷½µÏÿøå[Kuu‹].YW\Æ3dŒä Ãž|ÊÐkÂµa_êøÊwþ”c~n•…æjoÈÔ^r¸dbt~8Ø|•33ID ê¨£Vc&”Ñ£H¡::Ó_/þ8Àuæ£-¶edWHÂ5Þ’Lf:ä>œv*Jk¬±ŽÈ([å´³*«qÀÓŸ"uÀ%$š—¹Õf^¾Ä ¯ªøú«[öÐó_ZNDpÀºì²[ÄYï,‹–¼i©C/Ðê¨È‡Oôò–£FÕ–h£QúÖq+¥Qƒ¹Á0E˜¾°Ym©¬XPd‘oYDe¼…Å£Ï³Ðâ!íwúX °mÍú¨?nÝ†^®mí:‡Â5ðàF<è¼R“œíZñœ‹Ö6«’-0ŠyØÐ*ròw¼<ñ$³ÿC[Ë¡§^[ßZQƒFÔ D h! \³Hï[À¬Ú´kÔ=Šaè\«Ïþ+«®Ñ…3ú‰Ç'WõÛbŒ‚liƒ°ØjãŒ6ÚF ÇvÛÿ ÎÖ(PÇQ÷ç ÃVTh:cS÷Ä8ˆŠ9ïµ´¶§*®åËÍ:äü°Ø”£­Ãs”×VÖûÄ£ùZ’xúòuCh:y?ªÈéh¶ƒšjŽû£
```

except much longer.

How can I echo the image??

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Add this before echoing the image:

```
header('Content-Type: image/png');
```

P.S: instead of `image/png`, you should put proper content type like `image/gif` or `image/jpg`.

Comment: Doesn't that display the image on a new page?

Comment: No, that line just tells your browser the content it's receiving is an image!